# Curl returntransfer is empty, curl_getinfo "Error: 1"

Tags: php, curl, https, string

I try to get a page with curl from an IIS-Server which demands user authentication.

The curl_exec returns nothing, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is true. If CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is false the curl_exec returns true.

What's the problem? The page is neither after successfull nor after unsuccessful authentication empty.

```
$username = $_POST["acc"];
$password = $_POST["pw"];
$url = "https://secure.website.com/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
echo "Error: " . print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)) . "<br>";
curl_close($ch);

echo "<br>Page:<br>" . $page  . "<br>---------------------------<br>";
```

The script output looks like this:

```
Array ( [url] => https://secure.website.com/
        [content_type] => text/html
        [http_code] => 302
        [header_size] => 435
        [request_size] => 137
        [filetime] => -1
        [ssl_verify_result] => 20
        [redirect_count] => 0
        [total_time] => 0.187
        [namelookup_time] => 0
        [connect_time] => 0
        [pretransfer_time] => 0.046
        [size_upload] => 0
        [size_download] => 0
        [speed_download] => 0
        [speed_upload] => 0
        [download_content_length] => 0
        [upload_content_length] => 0
        [starttransfer_time] => 0.187
        [redirect_time] => 0
        [certinfo] => Array ( ) )
        Error: 1

Page:

---------------------------
```

curl_error outputs no error. The "Error: 1" at the end of the curl_getinfo is kind of my only hint.
The script works on other websites.

Comment: Which part of your code prints out the array with `http_code` in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the status code, which is a [302 Found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302), meaning that the page is issuing a redirect. Try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

This will make cURL follow the redirects for you, and should fix this issue.

(`Error: 1` is irrelevant, that's just because you're doing `echo print_r()`.)

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Why does `echo print_r(curl_getinfo($ch))` print `1`? Is it just transforming `true` into `1`?

Comment: @Shawn It's because `print_r()` echos the data, and returns true. When concatenated into a PHP string, `true` becomes `1`. To see it better, you can do `$x = print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); echo '----'; echo $x;`

Comment: Oh of course. The correct way would be to set `print_r`'s second parameter to `true`: echo print_r($whatever, true);